# Which unit vector $\vec x$ maximises $\langle A\vec x|\vec x\rangle$?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, inner-products, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a linear operator on a real finite-dimensional vector space $V$, equipped with the usual Euclidean inner product. Which unit vector $\vec x\in V$ will maximise the dot/inner product $\langle A\vec x|\vec x\rangle$?

Comment: for an Hermitian matrix, the normalized eigenvector associated to the maximum eigenvalue

Comment: @G.Gare indeed, if $A$ was Hermitian this would be trivial, but unfortunately it is not

Comment: I suspect that the eigenvector associated to the maximum eigenvalue of $A^\top A$ (i.e., the maximum singular value of $A$), plays a role here

Comment: @J-J: I think you can assume $A$ is Hermitian without loss of generality, because the quadratic form $\langle Ax \mid x \rangle$ is the same as $\frac{1}{2} \langle (A + A^{*})x \mid x \rangle$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assume $A$ is Hermitian without loss of generality. Indeed,

$$
A = \frac{A + A^T}{2} + \frac{A - A^T}{2}.
$$

The quadratic form over the antisymmetric part evaluates to

$$
\langle (A - A^T) x \mid x \rangle =
\sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^n x_i x_j (A_{ij} - A_{ji}) =
\sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^n x_i x_j A_{ij} -
\sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^n x_i x_j A_{ji}.
$$

By relabeling indices in the second sum and switching the order of summation, you can verify that

$$
\langle (A - A^T)x \mid x \rangle = 0.
$$

Therefore, the maximum is achieved by the eigenvector corresponding to the algebraically largest eigenvalue of $(A + A^T) / 2$.

Comment: Hence the maximum will be realized by the eigenvector associated to the maximum eigenvalue of $A + A^\top$

Comment: Another way to word the proof: $\langle A^T x \mid x \rangle = \langle x \mid Ax \rangle = \langle Ax \mid x \rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $A$ is a symmetric matrix. Then, to maximize with a constraint, you add in the constraint with a Lagrange multiplier, like this

$$\left<Ax|x\right> + λ(1 - \left<x|x\right>),$$

and maximize this by differentiating both sides with respect to $x$ to get

$$Ax + A^T x - λ(x + x) = 0$$

where $A^T$ denotes the transpose of $A$; i.e. $Ax = λx$, since we're assuming $A^T = A$. So, $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $λ$, and - thus

$$\left<Ax|x\right> = \left<λx|x\right> = λ\left<x|x\right> = λ.$$

The problem reduces to that of finding the largest eigenvalue $λ$ and, with it, the eigenvector(s) $x$ that go with it.